# Find source/origin of log4j logging statements?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, log4j

I have a Java EE application running under Glassfish.

After some recent changes we started seeing a spew of statements in our logs:

```
[#|2011-12-16T11:20:27.007-0800|INFO|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-62;|2011-12-16 11:20:27,007 DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection[Thread-62] - enter HttpConnection.closeSockedAndStreams()
|#]

[#|2011-12-16T11:20:32.007-0800|INFO|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-62;|2011-12-16 11:20:32,007 DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection[Thread-62] - enter HttpConnection.close()
```

We have set log4j.properties in an attempt to silence these

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=WARN
```

But that doesn't work. How can I find the source or origin of these log statements? What I think I want is like a stack trace that shows me what code is being called to cause this log statement.

Maybe something in here will help? http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

More importantly, how can I shut these statements up? They're polluting our logs.

Comment: You sure it's using your properties file? Sure doesn't look like it, because what you have works fine under normal circumstances.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is using my properties file. Is there a cheap test I can use to tell if it is?

Comment: Another piece of info, this statement hits regularly, every 5 seconds.

Comment: Where is your file located? You sure log4j is being used?

Comment: The log4j.properties file is located in my applications WAR.

Comment: ... Yeah. *Where*? And again, are you sure log4j is being used?

Comment: Now I understand what @DaveNewton was asking. I found out that I can pass the JVM `-Dlog4j.debug=true` and this will make log4j tell me where it loads its configuration from.

Comment: I'm so misunderstood! ;) Was it a case of it not loading properties from the place you thought it was?

Comment: @DaveNewton - It was exactly that. See my answer for the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is much simpler than I expected.

I found out that I can pass this argument `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to the JVM. It will make log4j tell me where it loads its configuration from.

It looks like this:

```
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/C:/Sun/GF2/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/MyProject/lib/omar.jar!/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.|#]
...
Parsing for [root] with value=[trace, stdout, R].|#]
```

I found that JAR in my classpath was packaged with a log4j.properties file (SLOPPY!) that had the root logger set to TRACE.

Comment: Ah, yep... an unfortunate default choice; at least it can be overridden or otherwise dealt with. Good find.

Comment: Here's a suggestion that wouldn't require changing a single line of code. Consider changing your logging to [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) and [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). They're written by the same guy who did log4j.  SLF4J can intercept log statements using other frameworks.  Just replace log4j.jar with log4j-over-slf4j.jar and all the log calls to log4j will be routed through SLF4J to your logger of choice.  Logback is a lot like log4j, just better. Configure logback (via logback.xml) to log what you want and you won't have to worry about the other loggers' configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is evidently something else higher up your classpath that is overriding *your* setting you can then grab the logger and set it right back.  Something like:

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;
...
Logger offendingLogger = Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection");
offendingLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

Comment: Once I have the logger can I do something (perhaps in the debugger?) to find out what might be overriding my settings?

Comment: Afraid not.  Log4J does not track who or what set the levels.  It could well be your introduction of `log4j.properties` told log4j **where** to send Glassfish's log statements.  http://blogs.oracle.com/naman/entry/configure_log4j_for_use_in suggests a way to segregate messages.

Comment: I tried adding this call to a class in my application and didn't have any change in behavior. What I think this tells me is simply that, like the log4j.properties, its a matter of finding the right place.